# I have four other Google accounts and I need my contacts lists from them for my new account. How do I retrieve them?

Tags: google-contacts

Need to find out how to get my contacts lists from my other Google accounts

What do I do now?
Can't remember passwords and which email address I used.
Want to sinc my contacts lists to my new email account.
Don't have a clue how to recover contacts lists from other Google accounts.

Answer (score 1):

You have to have the password of the accounts where you want to copy the contacts from.

1. Open gmail.com and log in with your new e-mail if not done already
2. Click on Settings (Gear wheel on the right), all settings, Accounts and Import \ Import mail and contacts
3. Put in the first e-mail you want to import contacts from and follow the wizard.
4. Repeat for all additional e-mails you want to import contacts from.